# If $E(X)=15$, $P(X\le11)=0.2$, and $P(X\ge19)=0.3$, what can be $V(X)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

If  $E(X)=15$,  $P(X\le11)=0.2$, and  $P(X\ge19)=0.3$, which of the following is impossible ?

1. $V(X)\le7$
2. $V(X)\le8$
3. $V(X)>8$
4. $V(X)>7$

I know $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.

Please, any other hints??

Comment: Here it's simpler to think in terms of "school" definition: $V(X) = \sum_i p_i (X_i - \mathbb E[X])^2$. Bound some terms and you'll get an answer. After that you can do this formally, e.g. using integral definition of Variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you have $P(|X-E(X)|\geqslant 4)$ and try to use Chebyshev’s inequality:
$$\forall\alpha>0,\ P(|X-E(X)|\geqslant \alpha)\leqslant\dfrac{V(X)}{\alpha^2}$$

Comment: i get sigma^2/16 . i am unable to solve it can you plz help me out

Comment: You should also find that $P(|X-E(X)|\geqslant 4)=0.5$. Notice that $\sigma^2$ is $V(X)$.

Comment: It gives $V(X)/16\geqslant 0.5$. This is impossible if $V(X)$ is too small.